# What does “mal pagé” mean?

Tags: sens

I came about this sentence "mal pagé". What does it mean? If we translate it literally, it seems it means "wrong page"? But, I think it should have some meaning as a sentence, doesn't it?

Comment: More context would be useful. Also, no need for thanks, thank answers by voting them up ; finally, the “France” tag is here for question which refers to specificity to the French language spoken in France as compared to French spoken everywhere else ; please try to avoid using unless needed.

Comment: For this question to be answered accurately, we need context.

Answer (score 2):

Literally, “*mal pagé*” does **not** mean “wrong page” as “*pagé*” is not “*page*” and “*mal*” is an adverb (badly), not the adjective “*mauvais*”.

“Pagé” is probably the past participle of the verb “*pager*”, which is slang for “to sleep“ or “to lie down”), used here as an adjective. So my best guess is it is slang for “uncomfortably lying”.

Comment: Indeed, French "***le** page*" is slang for "the bed" (different from "***la** page*" which means "the page"), and this expression clearly comes from the verb "*se pager*" (or "se coucher") - "to go to bed". Therefore "uncomfortably lying" seems accurate to me.